# React app with Typescript, Using generic spread expressions throw Unexpected token when trying to run the app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I'm using Typescript with react and i'm trying to create a component using **Generic in tsx**.
When I created the component, my IDE didn't complain about the syntax and everything seemed to be working properly, but then when I try to run the app, Typescript compiler throw an exception in the console telling me that the syntax is not supported so I assume that the problem is actually coming from by babel configuration.
I'm not sure if it's babel or webpack 
I tried different solution available in the internet but none of them solved the issue so far.

[image]
My component:

```
function AutoComplete<T extends { id?: number | string, [key: string]: string | number | any }>(
  {
    ...others
  }: Props<T>
) {

  return (
   <div> My component</div>
  )
}
```

How I use generic in JSX

```
      <AutoComplete
        <IContact>
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        dataSource={contacts}/>
```

**My tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**My eslintrc**

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "arrowFunctions": true,
      "classes": true
    },
    "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "browser": true,
      "node": true
    }
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  }
}
```

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "supplier-dashboard-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.0.2",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.0.5",
    "@bugsnag/js": "6.4.3",
    "@bugsnag/plugin-react": "6.4.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@types/node": "12.12.11",
    "@types/react": "16.9.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.5",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "antd": "4.1.0",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "camelcase": "5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "convert-vapid-public-key": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "is-wsl": "1.1.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "4.13.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "1.0.4",
    "react-currency-input": "^1.3.6",
    "react-dev-utils": "9.1.0",
    "react-device-detect": "1.9.10",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-intl": "3.7.0",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "react-router": "5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.12.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.4",
    "url-loader": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.9.29"
  },
  "size-limit": [
    {
      "limit": "700 KB",
      "path": "./build/static/js/*.js",
      "webpack": true,
      "running": false
    }
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "build:production": "NODE_ENV=production node scripts/build.js",
    "build:staging": "NODE_ENV=staging node scripts/build.js",
    "build:training": "NODE_ENV=training node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "REACT_APP_ENV=test jest --runInBand && eslint .",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "dev": "npm run start",
    "size": "npm run build:production && npx size-limit",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/*.js"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom",
      "core-js"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/config/jest/setupTest.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ],
    "browser": true
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env"
      ],
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.6.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.9.4",
    "@size-limit/preset-app": "^3.0.0",
    "@size-limit/webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "9.3.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/moxios": "^0.4.9",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.8.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.8.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-import": "1.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "0.3.4",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "9.0.2",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "6.6.0",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.7.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "less": "^3.10.3",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "ts-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your babel config ?
Also if you use typescript you should use eslint typescript parser
Replace your eslint parser `"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"`

Comment: I don't have babel config file, I put the configuration related to babel into the package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use typescript eslint parser:

```js
// eslintrc.json
...
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
...
```

And also extends typescript babel preset. [More about presets](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets)

```js
// package.json
...
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
       // you can use inline syntax if you don't need to pass config options 
      "@babel/preset-env",
      // Add this preset
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
    ]
  },
...
```

It should do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks for great explanation, but I tried that still didn't work, as I said i'm using IntellijIDEA and eslint doesn't complain about the syntax so I assume it's valid, still get the same exception in the console when I run the app

Comment: Yes anyway the eslint wont run/compile your code, so it's probably coming from babel / webpack

Comment: I had to destroy node_modules and do npm install again, that worked for me. Many thanks.

Comment: Nice :) The famous `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` haha